# Выравнивание блоков

Tags: html, css

Как сделать два блока, чтобы они находились один слева другой справа (две колонны). У меня правый блок отодвигается вправо, но находится ниже левого (как в нормальном потоке), мне же нужно, чтобы они были на одном уровне. Использую плавающие блоки (float). Пробовала свойство clear, но ничего не выходит. Надеюсь, правильно изложила вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container { overflow: hidden; }
    .container .left_column { width: 50%; float: left; }
    .container .right_column { width: 50%; float: left; }
</style>

Контент до
<div class="container">
    <div class="left_column">
        Левая колонка
    </div>
    <div class="right_column">
        Правая колонка
    </div>
</div>
Контент после
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xv96B/1/). Колонкам заданы разные классы, так как скорее всего у них будут разные отступы (например, если нужно будет добавить отступ между колонками).

Answer (score 1):

Если справа от правого блока в пределах одного родителя ничего не будет, то я бы сделала левый блок `float:left;` а правый блок `float:right;`, они бы упёрлись в стенки родителя и были бы по разные стороны. :-)

Comment: а ещё нужно не забывать новичкам напоминать про высоту элементов, содержащих внутри себя только плавающие элементы. А то будет потом масса удивления в ключе «а чегой-то мой подвал к шапке прибился между колонок?»

Comment: @Syabrowka, методом наглядного тыка смогут догадаться в чём дело и применят свойство clear. :-)

Comment: О, да вы давно не общались с новичками :)